# Cannot connect to server with Python ftplib, but PuTTY Plink works

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib, plink

Sorry, if this sounds too basic or if there is a duplicate which I haven't found during my search:

For example, these were not helpful:

- [Python ftplib WinError 10060](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44106200/7295599)
- [Python FTP cannot connect, but using client like FileZilla with same credentials works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058503/7295599)

And the examples of [`ftplib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ftplib.html) or from other tutorials are not working for me and the documentation is more confusing than helpful.
I must be doing something elementary wrong, or maybe there are special settings with my network configuration which might prevent `ftplib` from working properly? My configuration. Python 3.6.3 on Win10.

My question: what's wrong with the following code?

```
import ftplib

host = '0.0.0.0'
user = 'user'
passwd = 'XXXX'

with ftplib.FTP(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd) as ftp:
    print(ftp.dir())
```

After some time, I get the error message:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

---

Different approach using `plink`:

However, the following using [`plink`](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/plink-usage.html) works fine for me in the command line.
So, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the host, user or password or connection.

```
plink -ssh -batch user@0.0.0.0 -pw XXXX "cd SubDir/SubSubDir/; ls"
```

But instead of messing around with `plink` and `subprocess`, I thought `ftplib` might be more convenient. Thank you for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plink is an SSH client. SSH has nothing to do with FTP. You probably want to connect with SFTP, what is a completely different protocol that runs on top of SSH.

For SFTP in Python, use Paramiko or pysftp.

Comment: Thank you for your simple and clear answer. I was confused with all these different protocols (which to me do all the same thing) but apparently in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try a different approach to this , first make sure u have a connection to the target IP via ping, then attempt to login with the ftplib. here is an example , let me know if it's the direction your'e going for:

```
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP , error_perm
import subprocess
import time

def ping_to_target (ip):
    print(f"Ping ---> {ip}")
    process = subprocess.Popen("ping " + ip + " -n 10 " , shell=True , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    for line in process.stdout:
        if b"Destination" in line or b"Request timed out" in line or b"failure" in line:
            return False
    print(f"ping ---> {ip} done")
    return True

def some_func(host , username , password):
    if not ping_to_target(host):
        return False
    # CONNECT TO TARGET
    ftp = FTP (host)
    ftp.login(username , password)
    ftp.getwelcome()
```

i hope this is the meaning of your question

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess the connection is not the problem. As @tripleee tried to explained me, FTP and SFTP are two (completely?) different things (I didn't know this). And apparently, `ftplib` is the wrong tool. Hence, I should change the title to SFTP. And I guess I found a solution using Paramiko. I will post the solution when I have tested it.