# python FTP works in Linux but I get WinError 10060 in Windows - server is up

Tags: python, windows, ftplib

The following code works flawlessly in Linux, retrieving the list of folders/files available in the FTP server:

```
from ftplib import FTP
server = FTP('ftp.ibge.gov.br')
server.connect()
server.login()
server.nlst()
```

However, in Windows 10, I get the server welcome message after connect() and the '230 login successful" message, but when I try to send any command to the server - like `server.nlst()` or `server.dir()` - `socket.py` raises a `TimeoutError [WinError 10060]`

I am 100% sure that the server is up, and in Linux `server.nlst()` retrieves the information fast as lightning - so, it is not a "true" timeout error, if I set `timeout=1000`, or larger, I get the same error.

What is wrong?

Comment: Check firewall on both sides. Disable antivirus. Compare FTP server log for Windows and Linux clients.

Comment: I do not have access to the FTP server. The problem persists even if the firewall is fully disabled. I have no problem using Filezilla or the native Windows command line ftp app.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation of the problem can be found here: [passive reply with unroutable address](https://serverfault.com/questions/658427/server-sent-passive-reply-with-unroutable-address-when-connecting-to-ftp-site-wi)

It seems that 'ftp.ibge.gov.br' is not properly configured.

Luckily, I found a working [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814722/cannot-list-ftp-directory-using-ftplib-but-ftp-client-works).

However, it seems that ftplib is not able to handle this problem in Windows only. With Linux, I have been accessing files from this server for years using ftplib