# Specify external IP address for active mode in Python ftplib

Tags: python, winscp, ftp-client, ftplib, filezilla

I'm using active mode for transfers with my FTP server. In WinSCP and FileZilla there is an option for network external IP. If I give my IP in those boxes, I'm able to connect to the FTP server with active mode. But in Python I don’t know how to assign that IP. I can assign `ftp.setpasv(false)`, but it's not retrieving directories but shows you are logged in. But when try to run `ftp.dir()`, it throws error

> Exception has occurred: TimeoutError
> [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.  This is the error. I tried to set source address via ftp.connect function, but its not working, i tried to ignore return ip like some answers i found in stack overflow, but not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-implement the `FTP.sendport` to ignore `host` argument and send your desired IP address instead. Like this:

```
class MyFTP(FTP):
    def sendport(self, host, port):
        return super(MyFTP, self).sendport("192.0.2.0", port)

ftp = MyFTP(ftp_server)

# the rest of the code is the same
```

---

Btw, FTP servers are not *"in ... mode"*. They can perfectly support both modes at the same time. Much better solution is to use the passive mode.

This might help you with passive mode problems:
[Cannot list FTP directory using ftplib – but FTP client works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55814722/850848)